# Pass (–) through SendKeys in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, sendkeys

Can someone please help me in fixing the issue that I am getting while passing `–` (not a hyphen) through `SendKeys` in VBScript. Below is the code that I am trying:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys"(%chr(0150))"
```

0150 is the ASCII value for `–`.

Comment: The `–` is called "en dash" and is [Unicode character U+2013](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), so you would normally specify it as `WshShell.SendKeys ChrW(&h2013)`. Unfortunately, while that works from VB6 and VBA, it does not work from VBScript because [`WScript.SendKeys` does not support Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23078578/11683).

Comment: So how can I use this in VBScript? Or is there another way to use it?

Comment: I need to use this code in UFT, so any help around that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does or Can VBscript's SendKeys support Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198574/does-or-can-vbscripts-sendkeys-support-unicode)

Comment: @Sadique Check the second answer in the duplicate question and see if that works for you.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks for your response, but it is not working.

Comment: sendKeys "{SUBTRACT}" may help you but I am not sure

Answer (score -1):

I used ASCII character 45 and this worked

```
WshShell.SendKeys ChrW(45)
```